# Por que esse código não está mostra o resultado quando clico no botão?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function converterDuracao() {
  // cria referência aos elementos da página
  var inTitulo = document.getElementById("inTitulo");
  var inDuracao = document.getElementById("inDuracao");
  var outTitulo = document.getElementById("outTitulo");
  var outResposta = document.getElementById("outResposta")

  // obtém conteúdos dos campos de entrada
  var titulo = inTitulo.value;
  var duracao = Number(inDuracao.value)

  // arredonda para baixo o resultado da divisão
  var horas = Math.floor(duracao / 60)

  // obtém o resto da divisão entre os números
  var minutos = duracao % 60

  // altera o conteúdo dos parágrafos de resposta
  outTitulo.textContent = titulo
  outResposta.textContent = horas + " hora(s) e " + minutos +
    "minuto(s)"

  // cria uma referência ao elemento btConverter (botão)
  var btConverter = document.getElementById("btConverter")

  // registra um evento associado ao botão, para carregar uma função
  btConverter.addEventListener("click", converterDuracao)

}
```

```html
<!--
    a) Elaborar um programa para uma Vídeo Locadora, que leia o título e a duração de um ½lme em minutos. Exiba o título do filme e converta a duração para horas e minutos, conforme destacado na Figura 2.7.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Exemplo 2.2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Vídeo Locadora JS</h1>
  <hr>
  <p> Título do Filme:
    <input type="text" id="inTitulo">
  </p>
  <p> Duração (min):
    <input type="text" id="inDuracao">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Converter em Horas e Minutos" id="btConverter">
  </p>
  <p id="outTitulo"></p>
  <p id="outResposta"></p>
  <script src="js/ex2_2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

<!--
    O código HTML contém as tags de deÓnição da estrutura da página, dos  campos de digitação dos dados do Ólme e dos parágrafos para a exibição
    da resposta, a ser posteriormente preenchida pelo programa JavaScript.
-->
```

[Um exemplo de saída](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge4ZG.png)

Comment: Se você disponibilizou seu código como ele está, então está chamando `btConverter.AddEventListener("click", converterDuracao)`dentro da própria função `converterDuracao`

Comment: Opa !!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente mover estas linhas para fora da função:

```
var btConverter = document.getElementById("btConverter")

// registra um evento associado ao botão, para carregar uma função
btConverter.addEventListener("click", converterDuracao)
```